# Two keys, same function

Tags: c#

I just started coding yesterday however, I have ran into this issue and however much I google I can't seem to find the right answer.

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) || if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    target_right = new Vector2(transform.position.x + right_increment, transform.position.y);
    transform.position = target_right;

}
```

I have read online that || in plain English means or. I want both button D and the right arrow button to execute the code. How do I do this?

Comment: `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))` no need to have two if statements

Comment: You can read about the `if` keyword [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else), which includes examples of compound conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax should look like this

```
if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    target_right = new Vector2(transform.position.x + right_increment, 
    transform.position.y);
    transform.position = target_right;
}
```